# GCM not working on 8.0 and 9.0 devices but still working on earlier version

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

My QA team found that our push notifications to GCM aren't working on devices running 8.0 and 9.0 but still seem to working on the 5.x and 6.x test devices no problem.

The response from the GCM server seems fine for all pushes being sent out and I see no errors on the newer devices.

I know GCM is being deprecated but Google says that isn't until at least April 2019.

We have conversion to FCM on the schedule but there hasn't been time to do that yet.

Any thoughts, thanks.

Comment: While creating notification, have you set channel id?

Comment: What Android API is your target when GCM doesn't work?

Comment: Right from the GCM doc's `If you're targeting Android 8.0 (API level 26) or higher in your app development, use Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). Otherwise, use the JobIntentService class instead of the IntentService to handle token refreshes.`

Comment: So far it appears API 21 and earlier work correctly, 22 and later do not. We are targeting 26.